# Is there a way to make only the items in the recyclerview transparent?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

What I mean is, I want it to be so that each item in the recyclerview is fully transparent, showing the element behind the reyclerview. At the same time, the parts of RecyclerView which do not have a child element, I want them to be black. Is that possible?

Comment: A design prototype of what you want might be good to understand what you really want ...

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of your design requirements as per your description, however you should be able to set the transparency of both the RecyclerView and each rows view via `android:background="#00000000"`